# What is better to use for Android: Google Maps JavaScript API v3 or Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

What is better JavaScript implementation with using WebView or a native implementation?

Comment: Native implementation is better! use Google Maps Android API v2

Comment: This is not a question that could have a proper answer. It all depends on the context of use.

Comment: MaciejGórski. I use map only for Android. In this case is Google Maps Android API v2 better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native implementation works way faster and has cool features like animating camera along trajectory.

Comment: Such as I understand map Android API v2 is one product and map JavaScript API v3 is another product. And they is developed / updated separatly. (map Android API v2 is not deprecated. Otherwise it's used. (last release July 2013)) Am I right?

Comment: exactly. It's quite different API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using native Android application, native implementation is a lot better and faster. It is more customizable and controllable. You can also take advantage of native sensors in the native implementation. Try Google Maps API V2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Rendering of a WebView is slower, a lot more that you're rendering maps.